# cloudrail java desktop app

Tags: java, desktop, cloudrail

I'm trying to use cloudrail SDK in my  java desktop app for testing ,
 but I have problem with runing the sample  code in cloudrailsite;
 the following codes are main class:

```
public class DropboxWithCloudRail {
  private static String REDIRECT_URL = "http://localhost:3000/";
  InputStream inputStream = null;
  public void loadDropbox() throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
    CloudRail.setAppKey("*************");
    Dropbox service = new Dropbox(new LocalReceiver(8082),
            "*************",
            "*************",
            REDIRECT_URL,
            "Dropbox"                
    );         

    service.createFolder(
      "/myFolder1"
    );         
  }
}
```

I set the Redirect URIs in dropbox console http://localhost:3000/

but when I run the project , I get this page:

```
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Did you mean http://localhost3000.org/?
Search Google for localhost 3000
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you configure your LocalRedirect receiver with the port 8082 which makes it wait for incoming redirects on http://localhost:8082. So this is the URL you have to use as a redirect uri for Dropbox and not http://localhost:3000.

Comment: thanks a lot, I changed the port to 3000 instead of change the uri, and now it works.